# Load data to PartialView when click on calendar (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I using fullcalendar plugin

I can click date in calendar and get data from it

Here is code of script:

```
<script>             //Calendar initialization
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        events:"/Calendar/GetEvents/",
        firstDay: 1,
        selectable: true,
        select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#right2').load('@Url.Action("SheduleNewAppointment", "Calendar")');
            var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
            $("#startAppointment").val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a"));

        },
        editable: true
    });
});
```

By this  code I can get data

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#right2').load('@Url.Action("SheduleNewAppointment", "Calendar")');
                var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime();
                $("#startAppointment").val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a"));

            },
```

My problem in that I need to open partial view in `select` and add data to `#startAppointment`. It's input

Now it opens partial view, and not add data to input. 
How I can do this?

**UPDATE**

If i open partial view by another button and then click on calendar when partial is visible, all okay

Comment: Element with id #startAppointment is on this partial view you're loading?

Comment: Yes, it's on partial view@Lazys

Comment: I believe that you have problem with asynchronous execution of JQuery load function. Try to move code associated with setting #startAppointment value to callback of load function. It should looks like: $('#right2').load('@Url.Action("SheduleNewAppointment", "Calendar")', function () { $("#startAppointment").val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a")); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with Lazys' comment. You need to understand that ajax operations (such as .load) run *asychronously* and any code written on lines immediately underneath calls to async operations will execute *immediately*, without waiting for the async operation to complete.

Therefore, your code is trying access the `startAppointment` element and set its value before that element actually exists on the page.

If you have some code to run which depends on some data or markup which is returned from the ajax call, then you have to wait for the ajax call to complete before running it. That's the only way to guarantee that the code will have the values it needs available in order to execute correctly. This is usually done by means of a callback function which you give to the code making the ajax call, and this function is then stored up, and only executed when the ajax call successfully completes.

In the case of jQuery's `.load()` method, you can supply a callback function as an argument to the `load()` method itself, like this:

```
$('#right2').load(
  '@Url.Action("SheduleNewAppointment", "Calendar")', 
  function () { //this is the callback function. It's not executed at the time you pass it load, but only after the loading operation (done via ajax) has finished
    var allDay = !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime(); //I've included this line, although it appears to be redundant, since you never use the "allDay" variable afterwards.
    $("#startAppointment").val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a"));
  }
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more info.

If you do that, it guarantees that your partial page will load, including the `startAppointment` element, before the jQuery code which tries to access that element, and then you should have no problem.